# Using ALSA library on Linux

Tags: c, linux, alsa

`Ubuntu 18.04`

I'm very new to sounds programming in Linux and I'm trying to work with ALSA library. I have `alsa-library` installed on my machine as follows:

```
/dev/snd$ sudo apt-file list libasound2
libasound2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
libasound2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
libasound2: /usr/share/doc/libasound2/NEWS.Debian.gz
libasound2: /usr/share/doc/libasound2/changelog.Debian.gz
libasound2: /usr/share/doc/libasound2/copyright
libasound2: /usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples/asoundrc.txt.gz
```

But the problem is that my header files are completely different from what is specified in the [***documentation Files section***](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/files.html):

```
ll /usr/include/sound/
total 208
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 15 07:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 41 root root  4096 Nov 11 10:26 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 21847 Oct 23 17:44 asequencer.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19132 Oct 23 17:44 asoc.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4377 Oct 23 17:44 asound_fm.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 45851 Oct 23 17:44 asound.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6743 Oct 23 17:44 compress_offload.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16992 Oct 23 17:44 compress_params.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 17240 Oct 23 17:44 emu10k1.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2697 Oct 23 17:44 firewire.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3140 Oct 23 17:44 hdsp.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5486 Oct 23 17:44 hdspm.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4304 Oct 23 17:44 sb16_csp.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7494 Oct 23 17:44 sfnt_info.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11574 Oct 23 17:44 snd_sst_tokens.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4041 Oct 23 17:44 tlv.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1939 Oct 23 17:44 usb_stream.h
```

For instance no `conf.h` header and as a consequence no `struct    snd_devname_t;` definition. ALSA version I got from the alsa-info script is the latest one currently available.

```
!!ALSA Version
!!------------
Driver version:     k4.15.0-36-generic
Library version:    1.1.3
Utilities version:  1.1.3
```

Should I install some other package to get the all `include`s available? I did some file search

```
$ find / -name alsa 2>/dev/null
/etc/default/alsa
/etc/apm/scripts.d/alsa
/run/alsa
/usr/share/alsa
/usr/share/sounds/alsa
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic/include/config/thinkpad/acpi/alsa
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic/include/config/thinkpad/acpi/alsa
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic/include/config/thinkpad/acpi/alsa
/var/lib/alsa
/sbin/alsa
```

and did not notice them.

Comment: Check if you have libasound2-dev package installed.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that what the problem was about!